# Generic map method for spark RDD doesnt compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I can't figure out why this doesn't compile:

```
implicit class debugHelper[T](ar: RDD[T]) {
    def debug_restrainer(implicit sc: SparkContext): RDD[T] = {
        if (debug_size.isDefined) sc.parallelize(ar.take(debug_size.get)) else ar
    }
}
```

It gives this error: `No ClassTag available for T`

Does anyone know what it's complaining about?

Answer (score 4):

If compiler asks for `ClassTag` then it is most likely what you need. Also `SparkContext` can be easily retrieved from an existing RDD.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

implicit class debugHelper[T](ar: RDD[T])(implicit val t: ClassTag[T]) {
  def debug_restrainer: RDD[T] = {
    if (debug_size.isDefined)
       ar.sparkContext.parallelize(ar.take(debug_size.get))
    else ar
  }
}
```